# Как получить данные из ассоциативного массива?

Tags: php

```
foreach ($commentGet['response']['items'] as $comments)
  var_dump($comments);
```

я получаю

```
array(4) {
  ["id"]=> int(15)
  ["from_id"]=> int(156444354)
  ["date"]=> int(1525900033)
  ["text"]=> string(12) "Ляляля"
}

array(4) {
  ["id"]=> int(6)
  ["from_id"]=> int(23946139)
  ["date"]=> int(1525680565)
  ["text"]=> string(4) "йо"
}
```

Как мне перебрать массива чтобы получить значения from_id ?
Пробовал и for foreach но получаю null.

```
 foreach ($comments as $key => $value){
    $id = $value->from_id;

}
for ($i = 0, $size = count($comments); $i < $size; $i++)
{
    $from_id = $comments->from_id;
}*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выводите по ключу `from_id`.

```
var_dump($comments['from_id']);
```

Ваши попытки `$comments->from_id` неверные, такая конструкция используется с [объектами](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.object.php), а у вас [массив](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php).

Comment: Спасибо $from_id = $comments['from_id']; А как в дальнейшем циклом получать данные из массива ? А я же по сути получил foreach ($commentGet['response']['items'] as $comments) { уже массив и надо было просто обращаться по id .

Comment: Почитайте, пожалуйста, о работе с массивами по ссылкам, которые приложены в ответе. Обширная тема, желательно изучить самостоятельно

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        "id" => 15,
        "from_id" => 156444354,
        "date" => 1525900033,
        "text" => "Ляляля"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 6,
        "from_id" => 23946139,
        "date" => 1525680565,
        "text" => "йо"
    ),
);

foreach ($arr as $a) {
    var_dump($a['from_id']);
}
```

Работа я так понимаю идет с api vk. Тогда

```
$comments = json_decode('данные полученные от wall.getComments', true);

foreach ($comments['response']['items'] as $com) {
    var_dump($com['from_id']);
}
```